# unbound DNS killed immediately after starting

Tags: dns, unbound

I'm trying to set up unbound as my DNS resolver, but it seems that `unbound` terminates immediately after starting. Nothing in the logs seems to suggest why that is happening. This server has pi-hole installed on it and is also running an Apache webserver.

The config file is exactly as in [pi-hole's documentation](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/unbound/), except that `logfile` is changed to `/var/log/unbound/unbound.log` and verbosity is set to `2`.

Starting `unbound` using `service unbound start` will result in `systemd` attempting to start unbound over and over again.

```
Jan 28 15:58:51 srv01 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 28 15:58:51 srv01 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 28 15:58:51 srv01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Unbound DNS server.
Jan 28 15:58:51 srv01 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
etc..
```

Running it in the foreground shows this:

```
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] notice: Start of unbound 1.6.7.
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: increased limit(open files) from 1024 to 4140
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: creating udp4 socket 127.0.0.1 5353
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: creating tcp4 socket 127.0.0.1 5353
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: creating tcp4 socket 127.0.0.1 8953
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: setup SSL certificates
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] warning: did not exit gracefully last time (30708)
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: chdir to /etc/unbound
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: drop user privileges, run as unbound
[1584217278] unbound[31341:0] debug: switching log to /var/log/unbound/unbound.log
Killed
```

The log file output from the last run is:

```
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: module config: "subnetcache validator iterator"
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] notice: init module 0: subnet
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: subnet: option registered (8)
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] notice: init module 1: validator
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: reading autotrust anchor file /var/lib/unbound/root.key
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: trust point . : 1
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: assembled 0 DS and 2 DNSKEYs
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: DNSKEY:: .  172800  IN  DNSKEY  257 3 8 <redacted> ;{id = 20326 (ksk), size = 2048b}

[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: DNSKEY:: .  172800  IN  DNSKEY  257 3 8 <redacted> ;{id = 19036 (ksk), size = 2048b}

[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: file /var/lib/unbound/root.key
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: last_queried: 1584203277 Sat Mar 14 16:27:57 2020
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: last_success: 1584203277 Sat Mar 14 16:27:57 2020
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: next_probe_time: 1584242781 Sun Mar 15 03:26:21 2020
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: query_interval: 43200
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: retry_time: 8640
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: query_failed: 0
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: [  VALID  ] .   172800  IN  DNSKEY  257 3 8 <redacted> ;{id = 20326 (ksk), size = 2048b} ;;state:2 ;;pending_count:0 last:Sat Mar 14 16:27:53 2020
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] info: [ MISSING ] .   172800  IN  DNSKEY  257 3 8 <redacted> ;{id = 19036 (ksk), size = 2048b} ;;state:3 ;;pending_count:0 last:Sat Mar 14 16:27:53 2020
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: validator nsec3cfg keysz 1024 mxiter 150
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: validator nsec3cfg keysz 2048 mxiter 500
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: validator nsec3cfg keysz 4096 mxiter 2500
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] notice: init module 2: iterator
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: target fetch policy for level 0 is 3
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: target fetch policy for level 1 is 2
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: target fetch policy for level 2 is 1
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: target fetch policy for level 3 is 0
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: target fetch policy for level 4 is 0
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: donotq: 127.0.0.0/8
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug: EDNS known options:
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug:   Code:    Bypass_cache_stage: Aggregate_mesh:
[1584216438] unbound[30708:0] debug:   edns-cli NO
```

Is there any way of knowing why did the process receive a `SIGKILL`?

Answer (score 2):

can you run unbound manually in terminal by following

`unbound -d`

Because you want the early error in logs, unbound will verbose on terminal only for early errors before logging.